# Azure Service Bus Topic with some immediate Subscriptions and some deferred Subscriptions

Tags: azureservicebus

I want to put a BrokeredMessage on a Topic. Some Subscribers must process immediately. One or more subscribers must only start processing the next day.

I had looked into using the BrokeredMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUTC property to delay the processing of messages on Queues and Topics but this would mean that all the subscribers would delay their processing.

My thoughts are that I should add the BrokeredMessage to the Topic without deferring the enqueue time and create a Function on one subscriber that creates a new BrokeredMessage with a deferred enqueue time and add that to another queue.

[image: image showing process flow]

This seems like overkill. Am I mad or is there another way that I can defer the processing of one of the Topic Subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post duplicate messages with different ScheduledEnqueueTimeUTC to the Topic.

The Subscriptions should have Rules configured to it.

All the duplicate messages should have different set of Custom Properties, so that the messages will be sent to appropriate Subscriptions based on the Rules. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) for more details about the Rules.